# knockout computed observable stops firing

Tags: knockout.js

This is puzzling. Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sujesharukil/TCJjN/1/

I have a simple viewmodel and it contains a computed observable. The computed observable will return "" if a particular private variable _editing is set to true. Now _editing is not an observable. If _editing is false, then the computed observable looks through an observable and returns a computed value.

```
var expressionItem = function(){
    this.id = 10;
    this.value = ko.observable()
};


var vm = function(){

    var textVal = ko.observable(),
        _editing = false,
        expression = ko.observable(),
        displayVal = ko.computed(function(){
            if(_editing)
                return '';

            if(expression() === undefined)
                return '';

            expression().value(textVal());
            return ko.toJSON({Id: expression().id, Value: expression().value()});
        }),
        edit = function(){
            _editing = true;
            textVal('enter new value here');
            _editing = false;
        };



    expression(new expressionItem());        

    return {
        textVal: textVal,
        displayVal: displayVal,
        edit: edit
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(vm());
```

This works fine, till I set the _editing flag to false. Once I do this, and reset it back to true, the computed observable no longer fires.

Points I have noted.
1. If I make _editing as observable all works fine as the computed is obviously fired when the observable changes.
2. If I leave _editing as non observable and access an observable property much before my checks, all works fine too.

So, my questions are

1. Why this behavior?
2. How does the computed observable get re-evaluated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the value of the computed observable depends on the value of `_editing`.  Since `_editing` is not observable, changes to the value will not be reflected in the computed observable.

If `_editing` was initially `true`, the computed observable returns immediately without detecting the dependencies on the other observables and therefore never updates when those observables changes.

To fix this, simply make the `_editing` variable observable and should fix everything.

Comment: Jeff, _editing is initially false. The computed works fine till the time I set it the _editing to true. My question is how does the computed observable re-evaluate? since _editing is not an observable, the computed should not depend at all on it's value changing. Take a look at the fiddle. I don't think you have answered my question. Thanks however.

Comment: Right. As I said, `_editing` is not observable but you change its value in the `edit` function. By setting the `textVal` value, the dependency triggers an update on the computed observable.  Since at that point `_editing` is true, it immediately returns `''` and no other dependencies are detected. You change `_editing` back but since it is not observable, the computed never updates. Make `_editing` observable. [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeff1203/TCJjN/2/)